# A Strange Sequence

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, pattern

This puzzle is taken from a French bestseller I read years ago. The solution is much simpler than it looks...

Find the following line in this sequence :

`1
1 1
2 1
1 2 1 1
1 1 1 2 2 1
3 1 2 2 1 1`

Comment: An old question, but here's a variant: what starting sequence can go the most steps before reaching a length of ten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Say it out loud, and count the numbers!

So the steps would be:

> One 1; two 1's; one 2 one 1; and so one. The next would be 1 3 1 1 2 2 2 1.